# How can I grab with php and curl a tricky html page with double tables?

Tags: php, curl

I have this website here: http://www.wdjc.de/euro/index.php
its not like I only look for the solution without doing anything for myself,
but how every I turn this around I get stuck by the the
endpoint.

From my 2 ideas I normaly would build the script like this:

```
<?
$ch = curl_init ("http://www.wdjc.de/euro/index.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$page = curl_exec($ch);

preg_match('#<table[^>]*>(.+?)</table>#is', $page, $matches);
foreach ($matches as &$match) {
    $match = $match;
}
echo '<table>';
    echo $matches[1];
echo '</table>';
?>
```

this does not work at all it only shows me the table head.
so I got the idea to build this one:

```
<?
$handle = fopen('http://www.wdjc.de/euro/index.php', 'r');
while (!feof($handle))
{
    $html .= fread($handle, 4096);
}
$begin = '  <table width="900" class="clean">';
$end = '</table>';

$beginloc = strpos($html, $begin) + strlen($begin);
$endloc = strpos($html, $end);

$html = substr($html, $beginloc, $endloc - $beginloc);
echo "<table width=100%>";
$html = str_replace("</tr>", "</tr>\n", $html);
$html = str_replace("</td>", "</td>\n", $html);
$html = str_replace("<td width", "<td nowrap ", $html);

echo $html;
echo "</table>";
?>
```

It also does not work because of the end point  which is after every colum.
But the trick of this page is they use double tables:

```
<table width="900" class="clean"> <tr> <td align="center">
<br><br>
<table width="880">
    <tr>
        <td width="60" align="left">POSITION</td>
        <td width="40"></td>
        <td width="400" align="left">ARTIST<br>TITLE</td>
        <td width="90" align="center">LAST<br>WEEK</td>
        <td width="90" align="center">HIGHEST<br>POSITION</td>
        <td width="90" align="center">WEEK</td>
        <td width="40" align="center">COVER</td>
        <td width="70" align="right">SHOP</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<hr>

<table width="880" align="center">
...
```

Does anybody has an idea?

Comment: Instead of using `preg_match()` on `$page`, use something like `DOMDocument` or `SimpleXMLElement`. Parsing HTML with `regex` === `headache`. You can search stackoverflow for similair issues.

Comment: I have no knowledge about those how to use them :-(